# Bitbucket YLM pipeline to deploy on Digital Ocean

Tags: python, bash, git, bitbucket, digital-ocean

I am following [this](https://refwarlockprog.wordpress.com/2017/11/25/bitbucket-pipelines-vm-deployment-digital-ocean/#more-164) guide to create a pipeline to deploy my Django project to Digital Ocean, Ubuntu 18 droplet.

**What I have done**

1. SSH key generated and added to my remote server and bitbucket
2. Synced yml file with project
3. bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: python:3.7.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        caches:
          - pip
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - nosetests test/autotests --with-xunit --xunit-file=nosetests.xml --with-coverage --all-modules
    - step:
        name: Deploy to <myserver>
        script:
          - cat <script>.sh | ssh <user>@<host>
          - echo "Deploy step finished"
```

**ERRORS**
When I run the pipeline on Bitbucket I get the following ERROR

```
nosetests test/autotests --with-xunit --xunit-file=nosetests.xml --with-coverage --all-modules
<1s
+ nosetests test/autotests --with-xunit --xunit-file=nosetests.xml --with-coverage --all-modules
bash: nosetests: command not found
```

**Questions**

- `ssh <user>@<host>` I do understand how to replace `<user>` & `<host>`
- A.) How I should replace `<script>` at `cat <script>.sh`
- B.) How I should replace `<myserver>` at `name: Deploy to <myserver>` is this my server's IP address?
- C.) at the bottom section [this](https://refwarlockprog.wordpress.com/2017/11/25/bitbucket-pipelines-vm-deployment-digital-ocean/#more-164) guide has the following code I do not know what to do whit this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Deploy script started"
cd <project git directory>
git pull
sh <restart project>.sh
echo "Deploy script finished execution"
```

Comment: Your problem is "*nosetests: command not found*" so you don't need to debug `cat` or `ssh` (yet).

Comment: Your container  image python:3.7.3 either does not come with this utility - `nosetests`, or it's missing in your requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `ssh <user>@<host>`
   needs to have the user on your local server that you are trying to connect via SSH
   is the domain or the IP address of your local server that you are trying to connect
- How I should replace    at  `cat <script>.sh`
   is the shell script that you have written into your Bitbucket cloud repository
- How I should replace  at `name: Deploy to <myserver>`
   can hold name text and doesn't matter what is written on it
- Please use the suggested values and you should be good to go. All these are values of the variables which are non held by Bitbucket cloud and are in fact, what you have locally configured.